Target Version doesn't match project JDK version and Decomplied .class file, bytecode version error

hi.
I am currently studying Kotlin using Android Studio.
But the problem is that debugging does not work.
It runs normally, but when debugging, the following message appears. (please see image)

Target JRE version (17.0.10) does not match project JDK version (null), will use sources from JDK: jbr-17

I've searched for this problem, but most of the versions are from several years ago, so I don't know the exact solution.
I initially installed only Android Studio. And no settings were made.


In my understanding Android Studio just tells you that the Android device does not use the same Java 17 run-time that is used for compiling. As the Java 17 version is a J2SE version and Android has an own run-time the message is not unexpected. Have you installed in Android SDK manager the SDK sources for the targetSDK API you use in your app?

@Robert No, I've only installed Android Studio. I've installed it to study Android, but I've never created or run an app through Android Studio yet. I've only been studying Kotlin using Android Studio. I haven't installed anything like SDK.

Well, as I mentioned, I'm studying Kotlin at Android Studio. So I made any project, created an empty file called Test.kt, and wrote the code.

You are not debugging your code but the class java.util.zip.ZipFile which is a class from Java runtime. If you debug your code then you will see your source code.

I updated the image. I set the breakpoint and clicked 'Debug TestKt'. Am I doing something wrong?

Make sire you have not enabled to break on Exceptions. If the debugger breaks outside of your code simply continue execution (-> ignore the breakpoint).

I'm sorry, I didn't set anything up and I can't proceed.
